# How to store folder in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, blob, bytea

We have a requirement where we need to store mail templates in databases. these mail templates use some images. So we are thinking about storing a folder with images and HTML file in the database. The folder will have 200-300 kb of storage and we need to store 15-20 templates.

Which column type should we use to store folder in PostgreSQL? What are the different type of datatype for folder storage and which is the best in performance?

Comment: `bytea` is the data type to store binary data (up to 1GB)

Answer (score 0):

For storing images you can use [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/index.html)'s datatype [BYTEA](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-binary.html).

For the according HTML of that mail-template you could use [TEXT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-character.html) or [BYTEA](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-binary.html) as well.

Just be aware that PG might compress really large chunks of data..

The performance for the TEXT datatype is around 15% better than the ByteA datatype as tested [here](http://engineering.pivotal.io/post/bytea_versus_text_in_postgresql/)..

I hope that helped ;)